# Are there experimentally verified differences between general relativity and Lorentz invariant "newtonian" gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

I used to have (I lost it) a historical article about how Eintein's general relativity theory "won" over a Lorentz invariant generalization of Newton's gravity (I cannot remember the author). This is not the same as the gravitomagnetic approximation of general relativity, which is not Lorentz invariant, although they resemble each other in some aspects.

So my question is: Is there any specific experimental test (e.g., Mercury's precession) in which the predictions of the lorentz generalization of Newtonian gravity is disproved in favor of general relativity? Or is this for now just a matter of choice (for either beauty, historical reasons, or whatever?)

Comment: The gravitational deflection of light is twice as large as Newtonian gravity predicts. Is that something like what you're looking for?

Comment: @JimdalftheGrey do you have any reference? thanks

Comment: Not specifically, but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_general_relativity#Deflection_of_light_by_the_Sun) explains it and probably has references to the tests

Comment: @JimdalftheGrey If I understand correctly, the result you mentioned is based on standard Newtonian gravity and does not include any Lorentz-invariant gravitomagnetic-like effect

Comment: That's why I asked if that's the kind of thing you were looking for. Perhaps you could provide us an example of a gravitomagnetic effect that would be acceptable from such an experiment

Comment: @JimdalftheGrey when you said newtonian gravity in your question I assumes you meant the Lorentz invariant version I had asked. I'll try to find a link to this theory and update the question. Thanks again